# Find solutions of $a + b + c$ even, $3a + 2b - 3c$ odd, $a - 7b + 8c$ odd, in polynomial time

Tags: systems-of-equations, computational-complexity, np-complete

Suppose I have a linear equation in $3$ variables $a$, $b$ and $c$.

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
a + b + c &= 40 \\
3a + 2b - 3c &= 49 \\
a - 7b + 8c &= 77
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The solution to the above system can be found using the usual means and is $a=24, b=5, c=11$.

However, if I rewrite the same system in the below form

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
a + b + c &= \textrm{even number} \\
3a + 2b - 3c &= \textrm{odd number} \\
a - 7b + 8c &= \textrm{odd number}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Can a solution be found in polynomial time without using brute force techniques ? If yes, can the equation be extended to higher order and still solutions be found in polynomial time ?

Multiple solutions may exist but I want to know the process.

Comment: The original system can be solved in polynomial time, so yes.

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks but what would be the method other than bruteforce?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computational_efficiency

Comment: It is enough to put $2r,2s+1,2t+1$ instead of $40,49,77$ and solve as the first case with numbers so you get $$a=g_1(r,s,t)\\b=g_2(r,s,t)\\c=g_3(r,s,t)$$ where the $g_i$ are rational functions.

Comment: It's not clear: do you want to solve for having *any* even (resp. any odd, any odd) number for each of the equations?

Comment: @Bernard. Exactly yes. I want to solve for having any (even/odd) number.

Comment: Clarified question.

Comment: @carmichael561: You have approved an edit that introduces a multi-line in the tile of the post. This is not appreciated on MSE, because it breaks the alignment of the titles on the front page.

Comment: @NgChungTak: You have approved an edit that introduces a multi-line in the tile of the post. This is not appreciated on MSE, because it breaks the alignment of the titles on the front page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the system in $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$. Run the full row reduction algorithm on its augmented matrix:

$$ \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&1&0\\
1&0&1&1\\1&1&0&1
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&1
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&0&1\\
0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&1
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&1
\end{array}\right]$$

The solution is the last column. It means:
$$a~\text{even}, \quad b~\text{and}~c~\text{odd}.$$